# Use multiple column values for complex calculation of current cell value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe as represented below:

```
      A                     
0.00318492274476 
0.007763122173354
0.004294100473018
0.013777979548886
0.0034739588115
0.006684277028588
0.004035181028713
0.010939940038334
-0.000593509425213
.
.
.
0.98272

      B
0.007763122173354
0.004294100473018
0.013777979548886
0.0034739588115
0.006684277028588
0.004035181028713
0.010939940038334
0.000593509425213
.
.
.
0.078937
```

I am trying to calculate column **C** as in the below code:

```
operation_key = 'A'
operation_key_1 = 'B'
column_key = 'C'
df[column_key] = np.nan
for i in range(65, len(df)):
    df[column_key][i] = (df[operation_key_1][i-65:i].sum() /np.abs(df[operation_key][i])) * 65
```

This approach is going to be expensive for computation. I was wondering what should be the most effective approach for calculating the column C rather than looping? `rolling` would have worked but we can apply rolling on a single column !

Comment: just to help me understand your computation: you get the rolling sum of column `A` of 65 rows and then divide it by the value of in column B and multiply that by 65, correct?

Comment: Yeah correct, Thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: What prevents you from using `rolling`? `Series.rolling` exists too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code using rolling and sum:

`df[column_key] = ( df[operation_key_1].rolling(65).sum() / np.abs(df[operation_key]) ) * 65`